# Windows 10 , 11 explorer.exe Gui does not works after few days of windows installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-11

Windows 10 / 11 's explorer.exe GUI does not starts after few days of windows installtion , the explorer.exe process is still running but no GUI , it takes above 10-20 mins for GUI to start

Comment: Are you dual booting these two systems.  File Explorer works well on both Windows 10 and 11 machines (different systems) and so it is either something you installed or how you installed the operating systems.

Comment: @John i install windows correctly like shown in videos and also I install programs such as nodejs , java , chrome , android studio , Minecraft etc also I'm not dual booting I do clean install , I'm saying windows 10 / 11 because those problem happens in both operating systems

Comment: Start *Autoruns* as an Administrator and in options tell it to hide Windows entries then untick everything on the Explorer tab. Restart Explorer by terminating all Explorer.exe in the *Details* tab in Task Manager then in Task Manager *File* menu, *Run New Task ....*, type explorer. What happens now? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: I'm saying windows 10 / 11 because those problem happens in both operating systems   ... It is something you have installed. I have a Windows 11 Production desktop, a Windows 10 Production laptop and a Windows Insider laptop. The Windows 10 machine has been running for 4 years. The Windows 11 machine has been running for near 2 months. File Explorer works fine everywhere.

Comment: @John its only happening in Windows 10 / 11 also file explorer opens but the desktop does not , desktop [explorer] is running fine in win8.1 or lower

Comment: I don't know. No issue on my Windows 7 VM . None on Windows 8 when I had it. None on Windows 10 or Windows 11 Production either. So I do not know of any Windows cause.